# weblogic 10.3.3 integration with JPROBE

Tags: weblogic

I am trying to integrate Weblogic 10.3.3 with JProbe 8.3 But getting the following exception

```
JProbe Error: The Java VM was not recognized, so it is not supported.
JProbe Error: Unsupported JVM for this product: "C:\wls1033\JROCKI~1.0-6\bin\jav
a".
JProbe Error: JVM information: Oracle Corporation 1.6.0_17 (Oracle JRockit(R) R2
8.0.0-679-130297-1.6.0_17-20100312-2123-windows-ia32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like JProbe does not recognize the JROCKIT jvm that comes with weblogic.
Try changing the jvm in the weblogic startup script to use a sun jdk. Weblogic should be shipped with both sun and jrockit.

The script file should normally be located under C:\wls1033\server\ somewhere.
I think it is named startWeblogic.cmd or something. 
(I don't have a weblogic installation to check with, just worked with it earlier)